# vpath issue - not getting what i assumed

Tags: makefile, vpath

I have vpath set as follows:

```
vpath %.cpp $(SRC)
```

Now if i want to get the list of object files to be created, should it not work with the following ?

```
COBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
```

It is not. I am not getting any list of files when i run the command

```
make --just-print
```

It only shows the list of object files if i do the following :

```
COBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp))
```

Any explanation?

Answer (score 3):

The `vpath` directive will tell Make where to look for *prerequisites of rules*. It will have no effect on where the `wildcard` directive looks for files-- which is a good thing.